# How do you find a dropdown using an .is() method?

Tags: jquery

I'm having difficulty forming a piece of code that will search through a from, find drop down areas, and return the text of the value (ex: Blah blah) of the dropdown.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(this).is("select").find(':selected').text().show();
```

Comment: you don't. `.is` returns boolean. `true.find(...` is invalid javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd benefit from going through the examples on http://try.jquery.com.

To pull the value (text) from selected `option` elements within `select` inputs you can use:

```
$('select option:selected').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Refer to: http://api.jquery.com/each and http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector.